# Username is not displayed in title on answer timeline page

Tags: bug, status-completed, title, timeline

When you open the answer's timeline, the page title will be displayed as follows:

e.g. [Timeline for answer to Is prior research a must in all network sites? by](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/343583/timeline)

[image]

look at the [translate string](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/$?q=key%3A7deb1738ecdce3ee42f2183fdc6ef9a2), you should see the username after "by", but it is not displayed correctly.

```
Original String: Timeline for answer to $Post$ by $AnswerAuthor$
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: Seems like the actual fix is to make it match the question... and remove the "by" entirely.

Comment: @Catija I agree with that idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is now fixed. "…by $UserName$" should now render properly in the answer timeline `<title>` element.

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce the same problem and I agree with [@Catija's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343629/username-is-not-displayed-in-title-on-answer-timeline-page#comment1150972_343629) that:

> the actual fix is to make it match the question... and remove the "by" entirely.